# distorted appearance of subdivision mesh

Tags: shaders, subdivision-surface

I have modeled part of a car and found that over time the appearance of my model suffer.
its a low poly mesh with the subdivision modifier applied (also mirror modify applied)

render engine is cycles problem also exists in Evee
mesh appears fine without modifier.

I uploaded a screen shot. IF you can help it will be much appreciated!
Thank
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Philip there are many properties that can be adjusted in subdivision and object shading.  you may want to upload a reduced portion of (only) the mesh with your concern.   Have you tried the menu item "Object >> Shade Smooth"?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be due to auto smoothing settings or inverted normals

to check the normals, you need to enable backface culling

it is also worth checking for double vertex use
merge by distance

sharp edges are visible on the right side of the car, so should it be?

Comment: hi james_t and djastas, thanks for both of your answers! I checked the normals and merge potential double vertices, I also checked the "object>>shade smooth" the result is not what I wanted. however, all these tips brought the interface closer to me, since I`m an experience maya user, I had to find all these commands over time anyway :)

Comment: how can I upload my blender file for you?

Comment: to upload, use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload